# Не могу выбрать один элемент из postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

Выборка всех элементов методом `getAll()` работает, а выборка методом `get()` нет. Даже напрямую указываю строку, толку нет.

```
    @Repository
    public class UserDao {




    //todo 2) изменить подключение к базе через HikariCP к PostgreSQL

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
            List<User> users = userDao.getAll();


            for (User model : users) {
                System.out.println(model.toString());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("ошибка");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private Connection connect() {
       Connection connection = null;
       Properties properties = new Properties();

       properties.setProperty("user", username);
       properties.setProperty("password", pass);
       properties.setProperty("ssl", ssl);
       properties.setProperty("sslfactory", sslfactory);

       try {
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,properties);
           System.out.println("connect postgreSQL server successful!!!");
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
       return connection;
    }


    public void save(User user) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            preparedStatement = connect().prepareStatement("insert into users (login, firstname, lastname, email, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getLogin());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getFirstName());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEMail());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getPassword());
            preparedStatement.execute();
            System.out.println("Новый пользователь добавлен в БД");
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Ошибка при сохранении!");
        }finally {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
     }

     public User get(String login) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = connect().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        User user = new User();
        try {
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from users");
            user.setLogin(resultSet.getString(2));
            user.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(3));
            user.setLastName(resultSet.getString(4));
            user.setEMail(resultSet.getString(5));
            user.setPassword(resultSet.getString(6));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("ошибка");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ex.getErrorCode();
            ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null)
                resultSet.close();
            else {
                System.err.println("Ошибка чтения данных с БД!");
            }
            return user;
        }
     }

    public List<User> getAll() throws SQLException{
        Statement statement = connect().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<User> users = new ArrayList();
        try {
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from users");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setLogin(resultSet.getString(2));
                user.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(3));
                user.setLastName(resultSet.getString(4));
                user.setEMail(resultSet.getString(5));
                user.setPassword(resultSet.getString(6));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.getErrorCode();
        }
        finally {
            if (resultSet != null)
            resultSet.close();
            else  {
                System.err.println("Ошибка чтения данных с БД!");
            }
        }

        return users;
    }

    public void remove(String login) {

    }

    }
```

Comment: Сейчас метод `get` берет первую строку из выборки. А БД не может вернуть первой именно нужную строку. Потому ваш матов возвращает первую попавшуюся строку. Вообще вас должно было бы насторожить, что метод, получающий параметр lolgin нигде него не использует. Вам надо явно указать БД, что нужна именно определенная строка, задов в запросе условие `where`

Comment: указывал условие "select * from users where id = 1"  бросает тоже самое.   

ошибка
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkResultSet(PgResultSet.java:2769)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:1893)
 at ru.macakov.linkSaver.dao.UserDao.get(UserDao.java:83)
 at ru.macakov.linkSaver.dao.UserDao.main(UserDao.java:28)

Comment: Он вообще ни одну строку не может забрать

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from users");
if (resultSet.next()) {
    user.setLogin(resultSet.getString(2));
    user.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(3));
    user.setLastName(resultSet.getString(4));
    user.setEMail(resultSet.getString(5));
    user.setPassword(resultSet.getString(6));
}
```

Дело в том, что когда выполняется запрос, указатель ставится до result set'а. Далее его нужно передвигать и проверять имеются ли записи.

Например:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from animals");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо тебе, помогло!) Чтобы у тебя вещи после стирки не выцветали!